# Difference Date Calculation

Tags: php, laravel, date, date-arithmetic, php-carbon

i've problem with calculating difference between two dates (**including the End Date**) using Carbon. Here's the problem:

I'm using this code (source: danharper's answer in https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/carbon-display-age-in-years-months-day?page=1) :

```
$dateFrom = new Carbon("2017-01-01");
$dateTo   = new Carbon("2017-12-31");
$dateTo   = $dateTo->addDay();  //including End Date

echo $dateFrom->diff($dateTo)->format('%y') . " year, <br>";
echo $dateFrom->diff($dateTo)->format('%m') . " month, <br>";
echo $dateFrom->diff($dateTo)->format('%d') . " day <br>";
echo "difference " . $dateFrom->diffInDays($dateTo) . " days <br>";
```

**Scenario 1:**

Let's say, `$date1 = 2017-01-01` and `$date2 = 2017-12-31`, then it'll results:

```
1 year, 0 month, 0 day
difference 365 days
```

When i'm using date calculator in https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=1&m1=1&y1=2017&d2=31&m2=12&y2=2017&ti=on, it'll results:

```
It is 365 days from the start date to the end date, end date included
Or 1 year including the end date
```

They resulting the same answer. **BUT**:

**Scenario 2:**

`$date1 = 2017-10-01` and `$date2 = 2017-12-31`, then it'll results:

```
0 year, 3 month, 1 day
difference 92 days
```

Using date calculator in https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=1&m1=10&y1=2017&d2=31&m2=12&y2=2017&ti=on, it'll results:

```
It is 92 days from the start date to the end date, end date included
Or 3 months including the end date
```

The result in timeanddate.com is exactly 3 months **ONLY**. Not with **1 day**.

I want the result is **3 months** (the timeanddate.com's answer).

How can i achieve that answer?

Or, if it can't be achieved, is there any other technique to achieve:
`x months y days`? 
 (ex: `1 jan 2017` ~ `5 feb 2019` = `25 months, 5 days`)

Please help me.

Comment: You are using same date time object `$dateFrom` for difference measurement in terms of year month and day. Because of using same object, `$dateTo` is substracted again and again so your result is not the one you want.

Comment: @SagarGautam so, how i'm supposed to do the correct way?

Comment: I've added my answer, please take a moment to view it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change you code like following,

```
$dateFrom = new Carbon("2017-01-01");
$dateTo = new Carbon("2017-12-31");
$dateTo   = $dateTo->addDay();  //including End Date

$days = $dateFrom->diffInDays($dateTo);
$months = $dateFrom->diffInMonths($dateTo);
$years = $dateFrom->diffInYears($dateto);
```

In you code, you have measured difference many times instead of one time. Use `diffInDays()`, `diffInMonths()` and `diffInYears()` functions to get values of days, months and years between two dates.

Hope you understand.

Comment: what is `$datetime1` and `$datetime2`? And, is the `diffInDays` return the whole difference? (1 oct to 31 dec = 92 days) instead 0 years, 3 months, 0 days?

Comment: Based on your answer, if i : `echo $years . " years " . $months . " months " . $days . " days";`, the results: `0 years 3 months 92 days` (?)

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with you, I've executed above code and it gives me 365 days, 12 month and 1 year

Comment: Sorry my bad.. that answer is for `$dateFrom` = 2017-10-01. How to achieve `0 years 3 months 0 days` instead of `0 years 3 months 92 days` ?

Comment: @joshua14 just take diffInMonths() value :D

Answer (score 0):

**Scenario 1**

```
$start_date = new DateTime('1 Jan 2017');
$end_date   = new DateTime('5 Feb 2019 +1 day');

$difference = $start_date->diff($end_date);

$year_diff = $difference->format('%y');
$months_diff = $difference->format('%m');

$total_months = $months_diff + ($year_diff * 12);

$output = $total_months . ' months ' . $difference->format('%d') . ' days';

// would output 25 months 5 days
```

**Scenario 2**

```
$start_date = new DateTime('2017-10-01');
$end_date   = new DateTime('2017-12-31 +1 day');

$difference = $start_date->diff($end_date);

$year_diff = $difference->format('%y');
$months_diff = $difference->format('%m');

$total_months = $months_diff + ($year_diff * 12);

$output = $total_months . ' months ' . $difference->format('%d') . ' days';

// would output 3 months 1 days
```

Comment: for `$start_date` = 2017-10-01, how to achieve `3 months 0 days` instead of 3 months 1 days ?

Comment: Don't add the inclusive day in the end date

Comment: But if i not add the inclusive day in the end date, when `$start_date` = 2017-01-01, it'll result `11 months 29 days` instead of `12 months 0 days` (?)

Comment: Is your end date `$end_date = new DateTime('2017-12-31');` ?